# How to solve the integral

Tags: calculus, integration

Help to solve the integral 
$$
\int{\frac{\sin3\pi x}{x}}dx 
$$

I tried to solve by integrating by parts but this doesn't works

Answer (score 1):

The antiderivative of this function is the "special" function sine integral :

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trigonometric_integral#Sine_integral